# Error : 401 (Unauthorized) , Passport Authenticate in Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js

Passport authentication middle ware is used here, from Login api i have a jwt token generated and it is send to API http://localhost:3030/home/ in header but its throwing

error

> angular.js:12587 POST http://localhost:3030/home/ 401 (Unauthorized).
>
> angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"Unauthorized","status":401,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:3030/home/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Unauthorized"}

route.js

```
module.exports = function(app , passport){
    app.use('/login',userCtrl);
    app.use('/register',registerCtrl);
    app.use('/home', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }) , homerCtrl);
};
```

passposrt.js

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
var config = require('./appConfig.js');

module.exports = function(passport){
    var jwtOptions = {}
    jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    jwtOptions.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    var strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, next) {
        var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {id: jwt_payload.id})];
        if (user) {
            next(null, user);
        } else {
            next(null, false);
        }
    });
    passport.use(strategy); 
}
```

Home Controller

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var User = mongoose.model("user");
var express = require("express");
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./../config/appConfig.js');

//Type 1 using router
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/' , function(req, res, next){
    var formData = req.body;   
    getUserData(formData , function(user){
        res.json({ "responseMessage" : "Home Api Sucess" });
    });
});

function getUserData(formData , cb){
    User.findOne({username : formData.username}).then(function(user){
        cb(user);
    }).catch(function(err){
        cb(err);
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

Login Controller

```
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/' , function(req, res, next){
var formData = req.body; 
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

getUserData(formData , function(user){
    if(user){
        user.verifyPassword(password , function(err, isMatch){
        if(isMatch){
            var token = createToken(user);
            res.json({ "responseMessage" : "Login Sucess" , "token" :token});
        }else{
            res.json({ "responseMessage" : "Login Failed" });   
        }
    })
    }else{
        res.json({ "responseMessage" : "Login Failed" });   
    }
});
});

function createToken(user){
 var payload = {id: user.name};
    var token = jwt.sign(payload, config.secret);
    return "JWT " +token;
}

function getUserData(formData , cb){
    User.findOne({username : formData.username}).then(function(user){
        cb(user);
    }).catch(function(err){
        cb(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `passport.js` replace

```
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
```

with

```
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an Authorization header for every protected routes.

See the example using Postman:

[image]

**PS: You have to create a JWT token in the login process.**

Hope it can help you.

Comment: JWT token is sent in headers while http://localhost:3030/home/  is called.

Comment: Hmm... In the _passport.js_ file. Is this line `var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {id: jwt_payload.id})];` retrieving the user correctly? Because when you creating the token, you doing this: `id = user.username`, but you seems to trying to find by the `user.id`.